# Convert Olson/tz timezone time to universal time and vice-versa in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, timezone, datetime-conversion

Say I have time for a given Olson/tz database timezone, for example, July 1st, 1973 at 15h 23min in Africa/Maputo.

How can I convert it to universal time UT and vice-versa in `node.js`? I have seen some libraries online, but the documentation is unclear. A complete code example is welcome.

Comment: *Which* libraries have you seen, which bit of the documentation is unclear, and what have you tried?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/timezone and https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-timezone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) with [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/), and assuming ISO8601 formatting (you didn't specify).

**Loading for node.js**

*(web browsers can skip this step)*

```
npm install moment-timezone
```

```javascript
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
```

**Converting from local time to UTC**

```
var m = moment.tz("1973-07-01T15:23", "Africa/Maputo");
var s = m.toISOString();  // "1973-07-01T13:23:00.000Z"
```

or

```
var m = moment.tz("1973-07-01T15:23", "Africa/Maputo");
var s = m.utc().format();  // "1973-07-01T13:23:00.000+00:00"
```

The first form is more compact and is easiest if you are just sending the result over an API or saving it in a database.  The second form is an example of using the `utc` function, which is more useful if you intend to pass a parameter to `format` to produce a string formatted differently, or if you intend to call some other function than `format`.

**Converting from UTC to local time**

```
var m = moment.utc("1973-07-01T13:23").tz("Africa/Maputo");
var s = m.format();  // "1973-07-01T15:23:00+02:00"
```

or

```
var m = moment("1973-07-01T13:23:00.000Z").tz("Africa/Maputo");
var s = m.format();  // "1973-07-01T15:23:00+02:00"
```

In the first form, I show that you can use the `moment.utc` function to parse a string that does not contain offset information and have it interpreted as UTC.  This is the more explicit form.

The second form shows that when there *is* offset information (either `Z` or `+00:00` forms) it is taken into account. Though the intermediate result is a moment object in *local* mode, the underlying timestamp is still UTC-based, and thus the conversion to the specified time zone still gives the same output.